# Fourier transform formula

Tags: fourier-analysis

How to prove that $f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(n)K(x-n)$ where $K(y)=\sin\pi y/\pi y$

Here, $f$ is moderate decrease and its fourier transform is supported in $[-1/2, 1/2]$.

I show that $\hat f(k)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(n)e^{-2\pi ink}$ but no improvement...

Plz help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This formula is called [Whittaker–Shannon interpolation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker%E2%80%93Shannon_interpolation_formula).

Take inverse Fourier transform both sides of the formula $$\hat{f}(\xi)=\sum f(n) e^{-2\pi in\xi}\operatorname{rect}(\xi)$$

where $\operatorname{rect}(\xi)$ is [rectangular function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function).